# Windows File Permissions Administrator Denied Access

Tags: windows, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't rename a file in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/58200/cant-rename-a-file-in-windows-7)

(Running Windows 7 here.) I've got a dll file that I need to replace, which gives read-only access to the administrator, so even as an administrator I can't change the permissions. It only gives full control to the *TrustedInstaller* account.  What can I do to override these permissions?

Comment: Note that it is usually unwise to forcibly modify a system DLL.  For one thing, it may get reverted unexpectedly at some point in the future.

Comment: It's not a system-critical DLL, it's only used by one piece of software (I know because when I uninstall the software, the dll disappears).

Comment: Thanks surfasb, I actually did this already, but was wondering if there's a way to do it without changing the owner of the file...